# change background color of View dynamically in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

An array of colour is coming from database. I want to change colour of `View` dynamically respect to DB data(colour).

**Required output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPBWE.png

**My code**

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   {
       this.state.data.variants.map((data, index) => (
           var bg_color = data.option_values[1].value
           <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 30, width: 30,  borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: {bg_color}, marginHorizontal: 3}}>
           </TouchableOpacity>
       ))
   }
</View>
```

this code is giving an error that `unexpected token` at initialization of `var bg_color`. I don't know how to pass DB data to react-native style. Can any one explain how to pass DB data to style.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why you downvoted my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add logic to `map`, you should change it in order to return something:

```
{
   this.state.data.variants.map((data, index) => {
       var bg_color = data.option_values[1].value
       return(
           <TouchableOpacity style={{height: 30, width: 30,  borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: bg_color, marginHorizontal: 3}}>
           </TouchableOpacity>
       )
   })
}
```

Comment: yes I changed, it is working but not showing any result.

Comment: what's in `data.option_values[1].value`?

Comment: "option_values": [
                    {
                        "option_id": 1782916153430,
                        "name": "Size",
                        "value": "S"
                    },
                    {
                        "option_id": 1789080010838,
                        "name": "Color",
                        "value": "Red"
                    }
                ],

Comment: `console.log(bg_color)` before `return` to see what's in it.

Comment: I got it what is the problem I just append `.toLowerCase()` to `data.option_values[1].value` it showing me result. Thank you for answer.